# Is it possible to have a time triggered action method in mvc?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm working on a MVC project where after a certain period the app has to make changes to the database. I am using EF Code-First, and I would like to know if there is any way to have a time triggered action method in the app. If not, how can i make the changes?

Comment: Since MVC works with requests where do I implement the timer without any requests?

Comment: What exactly would be the point of invoking an action?  You're not getting input from the user and you can't send them anything so there's no benefit.  Sounds like this is a job for a scheduled task rather than the web application.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at the Azure Scheduler.

Comment: If you want to play with a shiny object :)  You can always check out the Message Queue pattern.  Basically, you write "messages" to a queue in your sender app.  You create a listener app that checks the queue asynchronously and performs a function.  If sender needs confirmation that a message was processed, use a second queue to report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static System.Timers.Timer EventTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1200); //Ticks
EventTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(eventClp_Elapsed);
EventTimer.Start();

private static void eventClp_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    EventTimer.Stop();
    //do something
    //you can restart again
}
```

You can try timers.

Comment: So I can only use seconds/ticks on the timer? Isn't there a simpler way with which I can perhaps use dates instead. And if I do use timers, is it possible to invoke an action method in another method even though there was no user request?

Comment: If you need something to run in any length greater than seconds (and perhaps minutes), you will need to look at some kind of scheduling/persistance outside of the scope of IIS as the session/application will be killed before the event triggers (and should do!)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have  a look at the Azure Scheduler.

Comment: I used the same approach in windows service. Which will check for entries in database table every 2 min, and initialize new thread or timer based on the request type. It is similar to scheduling. But windows service is an always running application.